# Adding the Bootstrap JavaScript library to application.js for webapp running on Rails 6.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails 6.0 the application.js is in a new path  /app/javascript/packs/ vs the old path app/assets/javascripts/.

I added these line the application.js file in the new path:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

but after saving it I'm not seeing the expected bootstrap dropdown menu.

Comment: I believe you might be interested to read [this tutorial](https://prathamesh.tech/2019/08/26/understanding-webpacker-in-rails-6/)

Answer (score 0):

The above snippet works for pre 6.0 but this solution was provided to me by another person to work in rails 6.0
1) $ yarn add jquery@3.4.1 bootstrap@3.4.1

2) add this to config/webpack/environment.js

const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
  })
)
```

3) add this app/javascript/packs/application.js

```
require("jquery")
import "bootstrap"
```